# Why am I getting an unknown error when trying to login with a user set-up in AWS-cognito CL?

Tags: javascript, authentication, browser, admin, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a login page for my app. It is pure html css and JS. I've created the user in the AWS-cognito cl but when I try to the use the credentials it fails to login and the only bit of information I get is that it is an unknown error.

I have tried to find something around this but nothing is really coming up. Alot of the answers I did manage to find would refer to the newPasswordRequired function or the version of the sdk being used.I have double checked and triple checked my user pool id and client id.

```
function signInButton() {

    var authenticationData = {
        Username : document.getElementById("inputUsername").value,
        Password : document.getElementById("inputPassword").value,
    };

    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId : _config.cognito.userPoolId, 
        ClientId : _config.cognito.clientId,
    };

    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

    var userData = {
        Username : document.getElementById("inputUsername").value,
        Pool : userPool,
    };

    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            resolve(result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
        },
        onFailure: function (err) {
            console.log("Error from cognito promise: ", err);

        },
        newPasswordRequired: function (userAttributes) {
            delete userAttributes.email_verified;
            cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, userAttributes, this);
        }
    });

    };
```

What I would like for it to obviously do is login and go to the designated page, I know the error function does work because before this I'd actually get info. I don't want or need the MFA for this either I just want to login with a user and pass that's been set up by the admin, it's possible that I've set something wrong in the cl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smart thing to have done here is to have looked at how I was handling the newPassword function. I wasn't giving it a way or opportunity to change the password as my app requires the user to be given the login which is admin created which requires the user to change the password upon login.

```
        newPasswordRequired: function (userAttributes,requiredAttributes) {
            delete userAttributes.email_verified;
            let attributesData = {name: authenticationData.Username}
            var newPassword = prompt('Enter new password ' ,'');
            cognitoUser.confirmPassword( newPassword, this);
            cognitoUser.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, attributesData, this);
        }
```